# Cannot compile OpenCV for iOS with nonfree module

Tags: ios, opencv, build, frameworks, surf

I'm attempting to compile the OpenCV framework for iOS using the nonfree module. Right now, I'm not able to compile the OpenCV framework, period. I would use the stock iOS opencv2.framework download from the website, except it doesn't include the nonfree module that I need for my project. I've been following the instructions as prescribed here:
http://answers.opencv.org/question/61663/how-to-make-opencv2framework-with-opencv_contrib/

as these appear they might be out of date

http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/ios_install/ios_install.html
https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/issues/4712

However, when I run the command from a folder outside the building directories "python opencv-master/platforms/ios/build_framework.py --contrib opencv_contrib-master ios_contrib" it spits out the following error:

http://pastebin.com/LUep8Tdw

The error doesn't mean much to me. I thought at first it was related to me building it inside the same directory as opencv, but I tried it outside of it and it still failed. Any thoughts? I've tried everything I can possibly think of, and done a bunch of research without coming up with anything.

Comment: I also tried using rc-1, just in case it was an error related to that version. It returned this error: http://pastebin.com/LWt7ZRq4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears there's some issue with one of the modules in opencv_contrib. I'm not sure what it is, but I was using version 3.0.0-rc-1. The way I got around it was by moving specific modules from the module folder in the contrib folder into the regular opencv directory's modules folder and then compiling the framework from scratch.